# Vue.js populate form fields values on modal using click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an html modal form that will allow me to update the selected post. I have created a click event that gets the data for the selected post which I then pass to the form and populate the fields. My issue is that if the form is hidden using v-if I get an error saying;

Cannot read property 'populateFormFields' of undefined

I'm assuming that this is because the component is hidden so the function does't exist.

What I want to happen is when a post is clicked in AppSummary.vue I want to get this posts data pass it to the UpdateForm.vue to populate the fields then I want to display this form modal. What would be the best method for this?

My code;

/src/components/AppSummary.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="summary_section">
        <h2>Summary</h2>

        <div id="summary_board">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="head">
                    <h3>Opportunities</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="body">
                    <div class="post" 
                        v-for="post in posts"
                        v-bind:key="post._id"
                        v-on:click="openUpdateForm(post)"
                    >
                        <p>{{ post._id }}</p>
                        <p class="company">{{ post.company_name }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <SubmitForm v-if="submitFormVisibility" v-on:formSubmitted="newFormSubmission"/>
        <UpdateForm ref="updateForm" v-if="updateFormVisibility"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import SubmitForm from './SubmitForm.vue';
    import UpdateForm from './UpdateForm.vue';
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        components: {
            SubmitForm,
            UpdateForm
        },
        data() {
            return{
                posts: [],
                submitFormVisibility: false,
                updateFormVisibility: false
            };
        },
        created() {
            this.getPostData();
        },
        methods: {
            getPostData() {
                axios.get('http://localhost:5000/')
                    .then(res => {
                        const data = res.data;
                        this.posts = data;
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log(error));
            },
            toggleSubmitFormVisibility(){
                this.submitFormVisibility = !this.submitFormVisibility;
            },
            openUpdateForm(post){
                this.updateFormVisibility = !this.updateFormVisibility;
                this.$refs.updateForm.populateFormFields(post);
            },
            newFormSubmission() {
                this.getPostData();
                this.toggleSubmitFormVisibility();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

/src/components/UpdateForm.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="opp_form_modal">
        <svg v-on:click="closeModal" height="25" width="25" class="close_button">
            <line x1="2" y1="2" x2="23" y2="23"></line>
            <line x1="23" y1="2" x2="2" y2="23"></line>
        </svg>

        <form @submit.prevent="SubmitOpp">
            <p>Update</p>

            <label>
                Company Name
                <input type="text" name="company_name" v-model="company_name">
            </label>

            <label>
                Company Type
                <input type="text" name="company_type" v-model="company_type">
            </label>

            <label>
                Line(s) of Business
                <select name="lines_of_business" v-model="lines_of_business">
                    <option disabled="" selected="" value="">Select Option</option>
                    <option value="Strategic Advisors">Strategic Advisors</option>
                    <option value="Strategic Sales">Strategic Sales</option>
                    <option value="Operational Support">Operational Support</option>
                    <option value="Claims Oversight">Claims Oversight</option>
                    <option value="Lead Generation">Lead Generation</option>
                    <option value="Transformation">Transformation</option>
                    <option value="Audit">Audit</option>
                    <option value="NED">NED</option>
                    <option value="Unknown at this stage">Unknown at this stage</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </label>

            <label>
                Client Type
                <select name="client_type" v-model="client_type">
                    <option disabled="" selected="" value="">Select Option</option>
                    <option value="Strategic Partner">Strategic Partner</option>
                    <option value="Retained Client">Retained Client</option>
                    <option value="Multiple Projects">Multiple Projects</option>
                    <option value="Single Project">Single Project</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </label>

            <label>
                Contract Type
                <select name="contract_type" v-model="contract_type">
                    <option disabled="" selected="" value="">Select Option</option>
                    <option value="Retained Monthly">Retained Monthly</option>
                    <option value="Project Fee">Project Fee</option>
                    <option value="Hourly Rate">Hourly Rate</option>
                </select>
            </label>

            <label>
                Contact Name
                <input type="text" name="contact_name" v-model="contact_name">
            </label>

            <label>
                Contact Number
                <input type="tel" name="contact_number" v-model="contact_number">
            </label>

            <label>
                Email Address
                <input type="email" name="email_address" v-model="email_address">
            </label>

            <label>
                Opportunity Owner
                <input type="text" name="opportunity_owner" v-model="opportunity_owner">
            </label>

            <label>
                Decision Maker
                <input type="text" name="decision_maker" v-model="decision_maker">
            </label>

            <label>
                Annual Jobs
                <input type="text" name="annual_jobs" v-model="annual_jobs">
            </label>

            <label>
                Average Fee
                <input type="text" name="average_fee" v-model="average_fee">
            </label>

            <label>
                Annual Value
                <input type="text" name="annual_value" v-model="annual_value">
            </label>

            <label>
                Next Steps
                <input type="text" name="next_steps" v-model="next_steps">
            </label>

            <label>
                Due Date
                <input type="date" name="due_date" v-model="due_date">
            </label>

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    //import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        name: 'oppForm',
        data() {
            return {
                company_name: '',
                company_type: '',
                lines_of_business: '',
                client_type: '',
                contract_type: '',
                contact_name: '',
                contact_number: '',
                email_address: '',
                opportunity_owner: '',
                decision_maker: '',
                annual_jobs: '',
                average_fee: '',
                annual_value: '',
                next_steps: '',
                due_date: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            SubmitOpp() {
                // handle submission
            },
            populateFormFields(fieldData){
                console.log('hi');
                // console.log(fieldData);
                this.company_name = fieldData.company_name;
                this.company_type = fieldData.company_type;
                this.lines_of_business = fieldData.lines_of_business;
                this.client_type = fieldData.client_type;
                this.contract_type = fieldData.contract_type;
                this.contact_name = fieldData.contact_name;
                this.contact_number = fieldData.contact_number;
                this.email_address = fieldData.email_address;
                this.opportunity_owner = fieldData.opportunity_owner;
                this.decision_maker = fieldData.decision_maker;
                this.annual_jobs = fieldData.annual_jobs;
                this.average_fee = fieldData.average_fee;
                this.annual_value = fieldData.annual_value;
                this.next_steps = fieldData.next_steps;
                this.due_date = fieldData.due_date;
            },
            closeModal(){
                this.modalVisability = !this.modalVisability;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach for this is to pass the entity to be updated directly in props:

```
<UpdateForm :post="post" v-if="updateFormVisibility"/>
```

And then do all needed logic in `created` hook of UpdateForm.vue.

Note that you will not need refs anymore and your component will not depend on somebody calling the functions.

Comment: Would that mean creating a post var inside data() in AppSummary and on click attaching the post data to it?

Comment: yes, you can assign it after getting it from backend